# No filter registered for [..]

Tags: elasticsearch

The ElasticSearch below query results in the exception:

> No filter registered for [formattedPrice]

When I only have a single 'must' terms filter, the query works, but that's not what I need obviously. What syntax does Elastic Search expect in this case?

```
{
   "query":{
      "function_score":{
         "query":{
            "filtered":{
               "query":{
                  "simple_query_string":{
                     "query":"yelp",
                     "fields":[
                        "trackName^10",
                        "sellerName^2",
                        "description"
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "filter":{
                  "bool":{
                     "must":[
                        {
                           "terms":{
                              "averageUserRating":[
                                 "4.5"
                              ]
                           },
                           "terms":{
                              "formattedPrice":[
                                 "free"
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "should":{
                        "exists":{
                           "field":"userRatingCount"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "field_value_factor":{
            "field":"userRatingCount",
            "modifier":"log1p",
            "factor":0.1
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the `must` part: it should be an array of elements of the form `[{},{}...{}]` whereas in your case you have `[{terms,terms}]`. It should be `[{terms},{terms}]`. You are missing a closing curly bracket and an opening curly bracket:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "simple_query_string": {
              "query": "yelp",
              "fields": [
                "trackName^10",
                "sellerName^2",
                "description"
              ]
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "averageUserRating": [
                      "4.5"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "formattedPrice": [
                      "free"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "should": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "userRatingCount"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "userRatingCount",
        "modifier": "log1p",
        "factor": 0.1
      }
    }
  }
}
```